# React: multiple components with the same event handler: trying to change the state of only the component which was clicked and not of all the others

Tags: javascript, reactjs, methods, components

I'm new to React and have to work on a specific assignment where all the logic of my app is in a single parent component and the child component only receives a few props. However, in the child there shouldn't be any logic or almost no logic.
I have a grid (**parent component**) made of 25 cell and each cell (**child component** ) can be either on or off. Imagine each cell as a light which is on or off.
From my parent component I'm rendering the cell component 25 times. Every time each cell has:

1. a key
2. an id
3. a status (on or off randomly assigned)
4. a click event

In my child component when the click event is triggered, the child component return to the parent its id and its status(on or off)

What I want to achieve:

In my parent component I want to be able to detect which child has been clicked and only change the status of the clicked child.

What I get so far:

Despite the parent receive the id and the status of the child that has been clicked, when I change the state via setState, all the children are affected.

Here is a snippet of  my parent component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import GridSquare from './GridSquare';
import { randomlyLit, cellIdentifier } from '../helpers/helperFuns.js';
let nums = []
cellIdentifier(nums, 25)

class GridContainer extends Component {
  static defaultProps = {
    gridSize: 25
    
  };
  constructor(props) {
    super();
    this.state = {
     cellID: nums,
      hasWon: false,
      lightStatus: Array.from({ length: 25 }, () => randomlyLit()),
    };
    this.changeValue = this.changeValue.bind(this);
  }

  
  changeValue(id, value) {
  console.log(id, value);
  this.setState(st => ({
    // let result = st.cellID.filter(c => c===id)
    // if(result){
    //   st.value = !value;
    // } 
    lightStatus : !value

  })
    
  )
   
  }

  render() {
  
    return (
      <div>
        <h1 className="neon">
          Light <span className="flux">Out</span>
        </h1>
        <div className="GridContainer">
        {this.state.cellID.map((el, i) =>(
          <GridSquare key={this.state.cellID[i]} id={this.state.cellID[i]} lit={this.state.lightStatus[i]} click={this.changeValue}/>
        ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default GridContainer;
```

Here is a snippet of  my child component:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class GridSquare extends Component {
    
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
       
        this.handleClick= this.handleClick.bind(this)
    }

    handleClick(){
        this.props.click( this.props.id, this.props.lit);
    
    }

    render() {
        const squareClasses = {
            'GridSquareOn': this.props.lit === true,
            'GridSquareOff': this.props.lit === false,
            'GridSquare': true,
        }

        function classNames(squareClasses) {
            return Object.entries(squareClasses)
              .filter(([key, value]) => value)
              .map(([key, value]) => key)
              .join(' ');
          }

        const myClassName = classNames(squareClasses)
       
       
        return(
           <div className={myClassName}  onClick={this.handleClick}>
           </div>
        )
    }
}

export default GridSquare;
```

My app.js only renders the parent component and nothing else:

```
import GridContainer from './components/GridContainer.jsx'

import './style/App.css';
import './style/GridContainer.css';
import './style/GridSquare.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
     
     <GridContainer />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: Have a look at [`Event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target)

Comment: @Detonar. Thanks for your attention however I'm looking into your suggestion right now but I don't see how I could use it. If I log evt to the console I don't see anything relevant that might help me to change just the state of the clicked component. I'm being daft maybe.

Comment: Event.target always contains the element that raised the event. So by reading it you could check this event's values. For example, `event.target.id` will always contain the `id` of the element which raised the event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
changeValue(id, value) {
  console.log(id, value);
  this.setState(st => ({
    // let result = st.cellID.filter(c => c===id)
    // if(result){
    //   st.value = !value;
    // } 
    lightStatus : !value

  })
```

Your change value function is updating the state with the wrong value.
Initial value of your `lightStatus` is an array of booleans ( assuming `randomlyLit` function will return a boolean.

When you click on one of the cells, the `lightStatus` gets updated with the value of `false` instead of an array.

To fix this, search through the entire `lightStatus` array by index for which the cell was clicked and update the boolean at that particular index using `Array.slice`.

**How to Optimise**

Instead of traversing the whole array every time to update the `lightStatus` of the cell. You can save the the value in an `Object`.

**What if I could update the status in `changeValue` like this ?**

```
this.setState((st) => {
  return {
    ...st,
    lightStatus: { ...st.lightStatus, [id]: value } // Direct update without traversing through array
  }
});
```

`lightStatus` can be used to form a "mapping" between cell ids in `cellID` and their corresponding status booleans.

Comment: thank you very much for this! You really made me see the Light ;-)
this is how I have changed my code after your answer:
```
 changeValue(index, value) {
    let flippedValue = !value;
    let newLightStatus = [...this.state.lightStatus];
    newLightStatus.splice(index,1,flippedValue);
    this.setState(st =>
      st.lightStatus = newLightStatus
    )
  }
```

Comment: @Emmanuel That's correct. Even though this will work, you can always optimise this to not traverse the whole array every time you have to switch one light. 
;)
Might be a good practice.

Comment: Please forgive me if I'm taking advantage but since your first suggestion helped me a lot would you be so kind to "just" point me in the direction of how I could optimise this without traversing the entire array? Thanks in advance

Comment: Thank you a lot for your kindness...I will try to implement your idea! Much appreciated